# Is the displacement of frustration a studied phenomenon?

Tags: terminology, psychoanalysis

I'm currently looking into [frustration-aggression theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustration%E2%80%93aggression_hypothesis). There is a lot of ancillary research on the displacement of the aggression generated via this theory, but I'm trying to find research on the displacement of frustration.

In this case, frustration, as defined for the purposes of this theory, is

> an interference with the occurrence of an instigated goal-response at its proper time in the behavior sequence ([Dollard et. al 1939](https://doi.org/10.1037/10022-000)).

What I'm specifically looking for is research that identifies a case where something else is identified with the frustration and/or misidentified as the frustration or in some way elicits the same response as the as initial frustration would under the frustration-aggression theory.

This differs from displacement of aggression in that the aggression itself is not displaced, but appears to have been displaced since the cause of the aggression, the frustration, is displaced. Has this concept been explored?

### References

Dollard, J., Miller, N. E., Doob, L. W., Mowrer, O. H., & Sears, R. R. (1939). *Frustration and aggression*. Yale University Press. https://doi.org/10.1037/10022-000